# how to subtract two table in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i have two table in mysql
1st is fees and 2nd is expenses

i want fees table subtract in to expenses table

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue thanks

fees table

```
------------------------------
id | name | grn | fees|
------------------------------

expence table
------------------------------
id | invoice | amount
------------------------------
```

this table showing only sum of 1st fees table

```
  // connect to the database
     include('connect-db.php');


    $sql = "select sum(fees) from fees";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);

    echo 'Sum: ' . $row[0];
```

This is showing like this
23445
 only 1st table result

```
and i want like  this
  23445 fees table result
- 3234  expense table result
  ------
  20211 total income 
  ------
```

Comment: show us your both table structure

Comment: http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1367071325.jpg http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1367056887.jpg see screen short

Comment: we can't see your screenshot

Comment: check my questn i update

Comment: Your table doesn't have any relations between.. so use @Mr. Alien code

Comment: dear i want like this fees - amount = result can u help me how can i use mr alien code in to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');


$sql = "select sum(fees) from fees";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$fees = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$sql = "select sum(amount) from expence";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$expense = mysql_fetch_array($q);

echo 'Fees: ' . $fees[0].'<br>';
echo 'Expenses: ' . $expense[0].'<br>';
echo 'Income: ' . ($fees[0] - $expense[0]) .'<br>';
```

Note:

Don't use mysql_* family functions because they are going to deprecated. Start to look into mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 1):

So store the results in a variable and subtract it, SIMPLEST WAY YOU CAN DO IT

```
$fees_amt = mysql_query($sql); //Returns say 10
$exp_amt = mysql_query($sql2); //Returns 5
$tot_amt = $fees_amt - $exp_amt;

echo $tot_amt;
```